# Do double vertical bars in ConditionalExpression mean 'or'?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions, conditional

I have a very simple interpretation question.  I think that double vertical bars in a ConditionalExpression given by Mathematica as the result of an integration must mean 'or', but I am hoping to check this.  Here is an example:[image: Example of double vertical bars in a conditional expression resulting from integration]

Thank you!!

Comment: Generally speaking,  you can always select an operator with which you are unfamiliar, then press "F1" to access the contextual documentation on that operator.

Comment: @MarcoB Wow, very useful information, thank you!!  I tried it and sure enough it led me to the link ojlm mentioned!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It is the logical OR function. It evaluates its arguments in order, giving `True` immediately if any of them are `True`, and `False` if they are all `False`.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html

Comment: Thank you!!  Great, now I can use the result! :-)